# Pandas - compare index and column between excel and dataframe to enter value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I have a dataframe like as given below

```
ID,DIV,APP1,APP2,APP3,Col1,Col4
1,A,AB1,ABC1,ABCD1,20,40
2,A,AB1,ABC2,ABCD2,60,
3,B,BC1,BCD1,BCDE1,10,20

region_1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',') 
region_1.set_index(['ID','DIV','APP1','APP2','APP3'],inplace=True)
```

And I have an excel file like as below. You can download them from [here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1874)

[image]

I would like to enter the data into the excel file if their indices and column names match with my dataframe indices and column names. For ex: `ID=1` and `Col1` (column name) matches between both excel and dataframe columns. So, we type in/enter the value 20 in to the corresponding cell.

I was trying something like below

```
all_rows = sales.sheets[0]['B5:B8'].value
region_1_cols = sales.sheets[0]['G3:J3'].value
sales.sheets[0]['G5'].value = region_1.reindex(columns=cols,index=rows)
```

But this doesn't work.

Based on SO suggestion, I tried the below

```
ws = sales.sheets[0] 
ws.range('G5').options(index=False).value = region_1.astype(str).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it types in the value in excel without any column name check or ID value check

[image]

Is there any iterative approach to do this using for loop etc. We need to retain the format of the excel as it is. So, we type in the value one by one based on matching criteria.

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)** can accept an entire DataFrame of filler values, in which case it fills missing values by matching the row/column labels.

So, create an empty DataFrame based on the Excel table and fill it with `region_1`. This avoids looping entirely, so it should scale much better.

1. **Extract the Excel table's row index and column names:**

   ```
   sales_index = sales.sheets[0].range((5, 2), (8, 6)).value
   # [[1, 'A', 'AB1', 'ABC1', 'ABCD1'],
   #  [2, 'A', 'AB1', 'ABC2', 'ABCD2'],
   #  [3, 'B', 'BC1', 'BCD1', 'BCDE1'],
   #  [4, 'B', 'BC1', 'BCD2', 'BCDE2']]
   ```

   ```
   sales_columns = sales.sheets[0].range('G3:J3').value
   # ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']
   ```

   Note: The exact `xlwings` commands might need to be tweaked (I don't have access to `xlwings` on Linux), but the idea is just to extract the row index (nested list) and column names (list).
2. **Create an empty `sales_df` from the extracted row index and column names:**

   ```
   sales_df = (pd.DataFrame(sales_index, columns=region_1.index.names)
                 .set_index(region_1.index.names)
                 .reindex(columns=sales_columns))
   #                         Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
   # ID DIV APP1 APP2 APP3                         
   # 1  A   AB1  ABC1 ABCD1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   # 2  A   AB1  ABC2 ABCD2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   # 3  B   BC1  BCD1 BCDE1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   # 4  B   BC1  BCD2 BCDE2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   ```
3. **Fill `sales_df` with `region_1`:**

   ```
   sales_df = sales_df.fillna(region_1)
   #                         Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
   # ID DIV APP1 APP2 APP3                         
   # 1  A   AB1  ABC1 ABCD1    20   NaN   NaN    40
   # 2  A   AB1  ABC2 ABCD2    60   NaN   NaN   NaN
   # 3  B   BC1  BCD1 BCDE1    10   NaN   NaN    20
   # 4  B   BC1  BCD2 BCDE2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   ```
4. **Enter the filled `sales_df` back to the Excel sheet:**

   ```
   sales.sheet[0].range('G5').value = sales_df.values.tolist()
   ```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW it'd also be a good idea to strip whitespace after reading the sheet. For example in `dummy.xlsx`, I noticed there's trailing whitespace in `'APP1 '` (and possibly others).

Comment: Thanks, do you use xlwings?

Comment: No, I'm on Linux and from what I could tell, xlwings only supports Linux through the [remote interpreter](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/remote_interpreter.html#remote-interpreter) paid feature.

Comment: Oh wow. So, you wrote the answer just by looking at my post? It works, so asking.

Comment: Yes, and also checking the [xlwings read/write docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#lists). I could test the pandas parts but not the xlwings parts.

Answer (score 0):

As there was no answer, I had to answer my own post. However, I do welcome any elegant and efficient solutions please. I can mark your answer as accepted. Anyway, you can look at my code below

```
df_value = region_1['ID'].tolist()
for val in df_value:
    for a_cell in sales.sheets[0]['B5:B8']:
        if a_cell.value == val:
            rn1 = a_cell.row
            temp = region_1.loc[[val]]
            temp = temp.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
            colu = temp.columns.tolist()
            for col in colu:
                for b_cell in sales.sheets[0]['G3:J3']:
                    if b_cell.value == col:
                        rn2 = b_cell.row
                        data_entry_loc = str(b_cell.address[1]) + str(rn1)
                        enter_val = temp[col].values
                        sales.sheets[0][data_entry_loc].value = enter_val
```

Though this works, am not sure whether this can scale for big data solutions.

Any better approaches are welcome

Comment: Your sheet has a fixed shape, no? It acts as template in fact?

Comment: Yes, correct. it acts as a template

Comment: Where `region_1` comes from?

Comment: that's the input dataframe

Comment: While my sheet is a template, I know the ranges `B5:B8` and `G3:J3` beforehand. So, I can hardcode it. Of course, a good programmer wouldn't do all this. But I don't know how else I can do this better.

Comment: but how do you know where you need to write in the cells if you don't use index of your sheet?

Comment: I make use of the index from excel sheet. B5:B8 refers the ID column in index of excel file (and compares it with ID column in dataframe). You can see df_value which is a list that stored all ID values from dataframe

Comment: Actually index column is only one column - ID. Meaning retaing APP1,APP2 and APP3 as index is useless because I realized that ID column can uniquely identify the combination of APP1,APP2 and APP3

Comment: Why don't create a dataframe with the same shape of your template (B5:N8) and write whole block. It could be more efficient.

Comment: Actually I had that earlier where I just copy the values as is. However, we found out that the dataframe doesn't come with same shape. So, I cannot copy. So, had to rely on this col by col check

Comment: So, you mean, even if my original dataframe doesn't come same shape, you suggest, I can create those columns for the sake of easy write operation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243187/discussion-between-the-great-and-corralien).

Comment: I will need your help mainly with logic verification (peer review) and also improvements to the code if any. I wish to know whether my code does the check properly between indices and columns

Comment: Your first line should be `df_value = region_1.index.get_level_values('ID').tolist()`?

Comment: Yes, correct. I will update that

Comment: Now, only thing is, i need to generalize this code for 3 regions. region_1, region_2, region_3. The code is same but the excel ranges used is different and temp dataframe will have appropriate region filter

Comment: For each region, you have only 4 columns (fixed width)?

Comment: @Corralien - yes, correct. they all have 4 columns only but different cell ranges as you can see in screenshot above