# pandas expand alphanumeric characters to iterate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a list with alphanumeric characters like as shown below

```
l1 = ['G1','L1']
```

I would like to know whether we have something like below

```
for i in range(l1):  #this doesn't work because range is only for numeric values
for i in range(G1:L1): #this also doesn't work
```

However, I want the `i` value at each run to change from `G1`to `H1` to `I1` to `J1` to `K1` to `L1`

Comment: Do you need something like : AA1 to AG8 for example?

Comment: yes, it would be useful to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range always expects a number and cannot work with strings.
However, you can use the built-in `ord()` function to convert letters to numbers and then use the `chr()` function to convert them back from numbers to ASCII characters.

##### Code

```
a = [chr(c)+'1' for c in range(ord('G'), ord('M'))]
print(a)
```

##### Output

```
['G1', 'H1', 'I1', 'J1', 'K1', 'L1']
```

#### Update: Solution for double characters.

Doing it for double characters is a little more complicated, but this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48984697/1764528) has a solution to that. You can simply use the `from_excel()` and `to_excel()` functions from that answer and replace them in my above code as follows.

##### Code

```
a = [to_excel(i) for i in range(from_excel('G'), from_excel('AG'))]
print(a)
```

##### Output

```
['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF']
```

Comment: @TheGreat don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem :)

Comment: It doesn't work for AA to AG ?

Comment: btw, one quick question - it doesn't work if I need `Z`?  doing this `range(ord('G'), ord('Z'))`, gets only till `Y`. I can't add +1 to the range because it throws error. Can let me know how can we get `Z` value?

Comment: @TheGreat you can just do `ord('Z') + 1`

Comment: @Corralien Yeah it only works for single characters. I could write a custom function that does that if that if OP wants

Comment: @DollarAkshay - Just so you know my question is in relation to this problem that I am trying to solve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567484/pandas-compare-index-and-column-between-excel-and-dataframe-to-enter-value . However, am not able to find a solution to this. Is this something that you would be able to help me with?

Comment: @TheGreat I have updated my answer. Let me know if that solves your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
from openpyxl.utils import coordinate_to_tuple, get_column_letter

def excel_range(start, end):
    t1 = coordinate_to_tuple(start)
    t2 = coordinate_to_tuple(end)
    rows, cols = zip(t1, t2)
    cells = []
    for r in range(rows[0], rows[1]+1):
        for c in range(cols[0], cols[1]+1):
            cells.append(f'{get_column_letter(c)}{r}')
    return cells

cells = excel_range('AA1', 'AC4')
```

Output:

```
>>> cells
['AA1',
 'AB1',
 'AC1',
 'AA2',
 'AB2',
 'AC2',
 'AA3',
 'AB3',
 'AC3',
 'AA4',
 'AB4',
 'AC4']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Upvoted. Do you have experience using xlwings?

Comment: No sorry I'm working on Linux that's why I use openpyxl

Comment: But openpyxl is probably already installed on your environment.

Comment: I already saw your question but it's really not obvious to solve :(

Comment: I perfectly understand your question... lol

Comment: I managed to write an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567484/pandas-compare-index-and-column-between-excel-and-dataframe-to-enter-value.   Can I have your suggestions for improving the answer? If you have any tips/suggestions to make my code efficient, I can mark your suggestion as answer for this post.